# npm uuid] Mocking doesn't work after the update in version

Tags: node.js, jestjs, uuid

After updating to version 9.0.1, I'm unable to mock the return value of 'v4' in Jest. jest.mock('uuid'), jest.spyOn(uuid, 'v4'), and jest.replaceProperty(uuid, 'v4') are all not working. My Jest version is 29.3.1. Is there a solution?

jest.mock('uuid')
ReferenceError: require is not defined

jest.spyOn(uuid, 'v4')
Cannot Spy on the v4 property because it is not a function; undefined given instead. If you are trying to mock a property, use `jest.replaceProperty(object, 'v4', value)` instead.

jest.replaceProperty(uuid, 'v4')
v4 property does not exist

```js
import { uuid }  from 'uuid' // version 9.0.1

...
jest.spyOn(uuid, 'uuid').toImplementationOnce(2); <- occur error (Cannot Spy on the v4 property because it is not a function; undefined given instead)
...
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: update for you in main text

Answer (score 0):

I don't see `uuid` among named exports for this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid

That trick when you import all the named imports as a default import might work or not work, depending on how package is built.

With proper addressing of named export it can be mocked without issues:

```
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";

jest.mock("uuid");

it("uuid V4 can be mocked", () => {
  uuid.mockReturnValueOnce("2");
  expect(uuid()).toBe("2");
});
```